# jQuery not executing even after .ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute some jQuery on my HTML page. I have research and discovered that you might need to insert `.ready` in order to make sure the DOM is fully loaded before executing the script. However, I can still not get the script to work!?

In the current version i have `.ready` after `$(window)`.

The snippet was found here: http://jsfiddle.net/ugcjtpd7/

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script scr="script.js"></script>

    <title>Dokument titel</title>
</head>

<body>
    <strong>Start coordinates:</strong><span id="start"></span>
    <strong>End coordinates:</strong><span id="end"></span>

    <div id="selection"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var start = {};
var end = {};
var isSelecting = false;


$(window).ready()
    .on('mousedown', function($event) {
        // Update our state
        isSelecting = true;
        $('#selection').removeClass('complete');
        start.x = $event.pageX;
        start.y = $event.pageY;

        // Display data in UI
        $('#start').text('(' + start.x + ',' + start.y + ')');

        // Add selection to screen
        $('#selection').css({
            left: start.x,
            top: start.y
        });
    })
    // Listen for movement
    .on('mousemove', function($event) {
        // Ignore if we're not selecing
        if (!isSelecting) { return; }

        // Update our state
        end.x = $event.pageX;
        end.y = $event.pageY;

        // Move & resize selection to reflect mouse position
        $('#selection').css({
            left: start.x < end.x ? start.x : end.x,
            top: start.y < end.y ? start.y : end.y,
            width: Math.abs(start.x - end.x),
            height: Math.abs(start.y - end.y)
        });
    })
    // listen for end
    .on('mouseup', function($event) {
        // Update our state
        isSelecting = false;
        $('#selection').addClass('complete');

        // Display data in UI
        $('#end').text('(' + end.x + ',' + end.y + ')');
    });
```

Comment: You should verify that jquery and your script are indeed loaded or if the console logged any errors.

Comment: @RadhaKrishnaEedulakanti this comment in not related to the above post, Please read `When shouldn't I comment` point. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: It actually is executing... See http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/5p8dj0yw/1/ I can still draw a rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @JuanMendes `$(document).ready()` waits until the entire DOM has loaded, whereas I believe `$(window).read()` is called long before any of the elements are ready.

Comment: ready is an event, not a function call, so you're not going to get a promise that says when the function completes do the rest of these things. when you bind the function inside the ready call, you're saying 'do this when you're 'ready')

Comment: @user290258 `$(window).ready()` does not exist, so it never fires. See https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: it sounds like the OP doesn't understand what is really needed.  Event listeners are needed rather than the READY.  Listeners start listening as soon as they can and do not rely on a 'ready'.  I see what @brentlyjdavid is saying about it running once when it's ready vs. listening so long as there is activity on the page.

Comment: @j_allen_morris Either way the event listeners should be inside a `$(document).ready()` block, and that's the key to solving their issue.

Comment: I agree, and that's the answer I provided and many others did too.  I don't understand why these answers have down votes.  Is someone downvoting everything?

Comment: @j_allen_morris probably because they were submitted well after the one that isn't down-voted/people didn't review the answers posted before posting theirs.

Comment: I understand that, except that my answer was posted 4 minutes after the other answer was posted.  I was writing my answer while the other posted.  Should I have refreshed and checked to see if someone else had already posted right before I submitted mine?  That would be dumb.

Answer (score -1):

First things, ready is an event just like you're trying to bind, so don't call it like a function.  I would change window to document

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function ($event){
    // Update our state
    isSelecting = true;
    $('#selection').removeClass('complete');
    start.x = $event.pageX;
    start.y = $event.pageY;

    // Display data in UI
    $('#start').text('(' + start.x + ',' + start.y + ')');

    // Add selection to screen
    $('#selection').css({
        left: start.x,
        top: start.y
    });
});


$(document).on('mousemove', function($event) {
    // Ignore if we're not selecing
    if (!isSelecting) { return; }

    // Update our state
    end.x = $event.pageX;
    end.y = $event.pageY;

    // Move & resize selection to reflect mouse position
    $('#selection').css({
        left: start.x < end.x ? start.x : end.x,
        top: start.y < end.y ? start.y : end.y,
        width: Math.abs(start.x - end.x),
        height: Math.abs(start.y - end.y)
    });
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function($event) {
    // Update our state
    isSelecting = false;
    $('#selection').addClass('complete');

    // Display data in UI
    $('#end').text('(' + end.x + ',' + end.y + ')');
});
```

Etc, etc, with the rest of your events you listed...

If you really need the events to wait to bind until the dom is ready.

```
 $(document).on('ready', function (){ 
     bind your jquery events here
 });
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but `$(document).on('ready'` is deprecated.  See https://api.jquery.com/ready/ `There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0` Also, I wouldn't remove the chaining since it has nothing to do with the question. Change only what's needed to answer the question

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Place your onmousedown and onmousemove in here
});
```

I haven't tried this myself yet, but it's what I saw that is different from what I usually do.  You don't have an anonymous function.  Also, if you place your code at the end of your file, you don't technically have to have `$(document).ready(function(){});`, but I believe it's best practices to include it so people later on can easily figure out what your code is doing.

Comment: Why the down vote?  I looked this up and it is the same as the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this seems like a suggestion without an explanation.